# Reverting draggables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

At the moment my draggables can be dropped anywhere in the grid.

I need the draggables to revert if they aren't dropped in the zone highlighted by the style.

How would I do this?

Currently I have made them revert if they arn't dropped away from the draggable's grid, like so...

```
    $('.drag').draggable({

    helper: 'clone',
    snap: '.drop',
    grid: [60, 60],
    revert: 'invalid',
 });
```

Here is the function that chooses the desired drop zone...

```
    $('#pickNext').mousedown(function() {
    // remove the class from all td's
    $('td').removeClass('spellword');
    // pick a random word
    var r = rndWord;
    while (r == rndWord) {
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
}
    // apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
    $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});
```

Something like this...

```
    $('.squares').draggable({

    drop: function(event, ui){
    if (squares.drop ! word) {
    revert: 'invalid'
    }

  }

});
```

Or this..

```
$('.squares').draggable({

    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {
            revert: 'valid'
        }
                else {
                revert: 'invalid'
    }
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make new new `drop` zones that match the given letter each time you start dragging a letter. Currently, every letter is a `droppable`, which isn't what you want.

To do that, I modified your JSFiddle to create drop zones using a function called `makeDroppables()` each time a letter starts being dragged.

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/uu99V/)

Note: Answer edited to fit question more closely.

Also, from the [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert) on draggable:

> "If set to invalid, revert will only occur 
>   if the draggable has not been dropped on a droppable."

Comment: Is there no simpler way of doing it? @briangonzalez

Comment: I definately will as it is perfect. What would I do if I wanted the ".spellword" to allow wrong letters @briangonazalez

Comment: Change `var validDrop = $('.drop-box.spellword[data-letter='+ $(this).attr('data-letter') +']');` to `var validDrop = $('.drop-box.spellword');`

Comment: What if I want to revert if not in the first cell of the word, but still be able to put the wrong letter in? @briangonzalez

Comment: How do you think you would do it?

Comment: I have tried    var validDrop = $('.drop-box.spellword[data-letter='+ $(this).attr('.squares') +']'); and var validDrop = $('.drop-box.spellword[data-letter='+ $(this).attr('.drop') +']'); @briangonzalez

Comment: Add another attribute `data-first-letter` to only the first letter of the word. Add the `drop` class to those with that attribute.

Comment: Could you tell me why this doesn't work?                                  var validDrop = $('.drop-box.spellword[firstData-letter='+ $(this).attr('data-letter') +']'); @briangonzalex

Comment: Read up on data attributes, therr are some rules. http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/